# Update FullCalendar event when external draggable event is dropped on top

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, fullcalendar

I have a FullCalendar component in my react project that is working great. As it stands now, I can create elements by selecting on the calendar or by dragging external events from a list onto the calendar.

I want to add a feature where external events dropped on top of existing events will simply update the existing event instead of creating a concurrent event. This is happening inside of a `timeGridDay` view.

My current attempt involves adding the `eventMouseEnter` callback to existing events and simply updating the event if `drop` is called when `eventMouseEnter` is true. The problem is that the `drop` callback is always called first. Does anyone know of an approach to solve this?

Here is an image of what is happening now when the `testing 1` event is dragged onto the existing event. Desired behavior is for the blue event to receive all data from `testing 1` at which point I will update update the event on the front and backend.

[image]